# How can I get a count of the frequency of lines among many files?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have many (i.e. >> 2) text files.  These files are all mostly similar but have some small differences between them.  I would like to find the lines that most commonly appear among these files.  For instance, here is the type of information I am looking for (I only care about the data; by no means is any particular formatting necessary):

```
$ cat file1
line1line1line1
line2line2line2
line3line3line3
$ cat file2
line1line1line1
line2line2line2
$ cat file3
line1line1line1
line3line3line3
$ cat file4
line4line4line4
$ my_awesome_script file{1,2,3,4}
count | line
------+----------------
    3 | line1line1line1
    2 | line2line2line2
    2 | line3line3line3
    1 | line4line4line4
```

There are some common tools to do similar tasks, however, they have some limitations:

- `comm` - can only compare two files at once; throws away lines that don't appear in both files
- `grep -f` - throws away lines that don't match
- `grep -c` - counts matches, but outputs a total count per file and throws away information about which input patterns match

For clarification's sake, if a line appears multiple times in one file, I only count that as one match. I just care about how many files the lines appear in, not how many times the lines appear in total.

Comment: Thank you @SatoKatsura. I totally forgot about `uniq`.  Please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
#! /bin/sh
for f in ./file*; do
    sort -u "$f"
done | \
    sort | \
    uniq -c | \
    sort -rn | \
    head -40
```

The point of the `for` is to make sure each line is counted only once per file.  The point of the rest of the pipeline is to count the occurrences.